# c++ Issues with function assigning values to class/struct

Tags: c++

I have a class called Funcionario like this :

```
class Funcionario
{
public:
    string nome;
    int cpf;

    void preencher(string nome, int cpf);
};
```

and the function preencher works like this :

```
void Funcionario::preencher(string nome, int cpf)
{
    this->nome = nome;
    this->cpf = cpf;
}
```

On the main function i declared the Funcionario func and everything works fine when i set the name and cpf directly with

```
    cin >> Func.nome >> Func.cpf;
```

or calling the function like this :

```
    string nome;
    int cpf;
    cin >> nome >> cpf;

    Func.preencher(nome, cpf);
```

But i tried to do things differently and i got a problem.
instead of declaring the function preencher inside Funcionario, i declared the function outside of it with a parameter of the type Funcionario
and then setting the "nome" and "cpf" values in the function like this :

```
void preencher(Funcionario func)
{
    cin >> func.nome;
    cin >> func.cpf;
}
```

If i try to set the Func nome and cpf directly with

```
cin >> Func.cpf >> Func.nome;
```

it works fine.
However, if i try to call the new preencher function like that

```
preencher(Func);
```

with the nome = joao and cpf = 7842 , for example,
when i print the name i get a null string and when i print the int cpf i get very weird values like -1425739872 or -1121695152.
Why does the first method works fine when printing(and assigning values aswell) but the second one doesn't?
I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate question , but i tried really hard to find a solution but i just couldn't.

Comment: Try `void preencher(Funcionario &func)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass func by reference for the non-member case. You are actually setting the members of the local 'func' but that has nothing to do with the instance in the calling function.

Comment: I just fixed it doing this. Another guy answered this a while ago but we both deleted our answers, i googled pass by reference and pass by value and fixed it.

Comment: @NaviSeven, it is better to be more interactive with people in the comments. If you see something abusvie just flag and ignore.

Comment: @Incomputable okie dokie.